# Cannot remove duplicates from a list<string> with Distinct method

Tags: c#, string, list

I already searched many solutions and couldn't find any that helped me.

I gather data from a `iWebElement`, add it to a `List`, convert it to `string` and later to a `List<string>` that's when I try to do . `Distinct()` resulting on nothing.

```
var h1Heading = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//h1"));
ListOfKeywords.AddRange(h1Heading);
foreach (IWebElement keywords in ListOfKeywords)
{
   cleaned.Add(keywords.Text);
}
cleaned.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: `Distinct()` _returns_ an ienumerable with no duplicates. you have to _assign_ it to a variable, though, it does **not** change the original _in place_ - try `cleaned = cleaned.Distinct().ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simplify this by doing this:

```
var h1Heading = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//h1"));
ListOfKeywords.AddRange(h1Heading);
// Create a cleanup the list and assign it to the cleaned variable
cleaned = ListOfKeywords 
            .Select(l => l.Text) // No need for unessecary foreach
            .Distinct() // Create the distinct IEnumerable
            .ToList(); // Cast it to a new list
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var mylist = cleaned.Distinct().ToList();
```

mylist has cleaned items after distinct